# Use JSPs without defining a servlet-mapping for them?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is there a way to work with JSPs by only dispatching to them from a servlet, without having a `<servlet-mapping>` in web.xml that maps to the JspServlet (Tomcat 7)?

I want to build a webapp which uses a controller servlet to handle the input and perform the processing and finally handing over to a JSP for Rendering; i.e. classic MVC pattern.

So, the servlet includes (or forwards to) the JSP with

```
request.getRequestDispatcher( "/view.jsp" ).include( request, response );
```

To make this work, it seems that there is no other way than to have a `<servlet-mapping>` in the web.xml which maps the `"/view.jsp"` to the JspServlet. (Whatever that mapping is.)

The key question: **Is there a way to use JSPs without exposing them by a servlet-mapping?**
If the JSPs are mapped, then direct requests to them are possible, and this should be avoided.
The view JSPs will not work if called directly, missing the data beans provided by the
controller servlet.

No Framework whatsoever used.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to access to the JSPs directly w/o usage of a servlet?

Comment: No, the JSPs are to be invoked only from the Controller servlet.

Comment: Oh, so only the servlet can invoke it, external users cannot see their contents, right?

Comment: Put your JSP into `WEB-INF` folder and even with a servlet mapping, they will not be accessible. I don't hink you can easily use JSP without the JSP servlet

Comment: Yes. Ok, the contents, i.e. the source code, should certainly not be seen anyway... and this leads to another  important aspect: If the JSPs are not mapped to the JspServlet, but reside in an accessible folder of the webapp, then it must be made sure that they are not served by the DefaultServlet, otherwise they _will_ be served in source.

Comment: @NicolasLabrot  You're right. Only the servlet mapping has to be generic. It must not _directly_ link to the JSP, like <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/view.jsp</jsp-file>.  It works with e.g. the generic mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember standard way of preventing user from directly accessing resources (like JSP) on server but at the same time allowing server to access them is by placing them in `WEB-INF` folder. So you could try something more like

```
request.getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/views/view.jsp" ).include( request, response );
```

Comment: Yeah, right. This does it.  I was trying this before, but then using a <servlet> definition with `<jsp-file>/WEB-INF/view.jsp</jsp-file>` and mapping <url-pattern>/view</url-pattern> to this servlet. That way, the JSP can still be invoked directly with a URL `/app/view`.  The solution is to use a **generic mapping** like the default *.jsp. This way, the client would have to invoke `/app/WEB-INF/view.jsp` to get to the JSP directly and this, of course, is blocked.

Comment: Sorry, but why do you even want to have JSP mapping in your web.xml (I am not JEE expert so I am kind of curious what you are trying to achieve here)?

Comment: Without mapping there's no processing. Usually there is no mapping for JSPs in an application's web.xml since there is a set of _default_ mappings: `*.jsp` maps to the JspServlet (speaking of Tomcat). There is another, global web.xml in `${catalina.base}/conf` which is added to each apps web.xml.  I am using an explicit map in my app's web.xml because I defined a map for the servlet path `"/"` i.e. which is the fall-back for all other paths for which no more specific mapping can be found. By using a mapping for `"/"` you disable the Default mapping for `*.jsp`, hence need to add it again.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarification. Actually now I see that my answer doesn't fully answer your question. So feel free to post your own answer where you will explain solution with generic mapping. I will not mind if you accept your answer over mine.